# Automated build with CodeBuild not working on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to automate the build process with my MERN stack web app.

Currently, I use CodePipeline which:

1. Fetches my code from GitHub as the Source
2. Runs the build using CodeBuild (Ubuntu 2.0)
3. And deploys it to my Elastic BeanStalk environment.

Steps 1 & 3 have worked perfectly before, but I always had to run my build before making my final git push which made it irritating to have all the build files included in Code Reviews.

After attempting to use CodeBuild, even though the client seems to build perfectly according to the logs, the front-end doesn't seem to update.

Here is a snippet from the successful build logs: 
[image]
This is how my `buildspec.yml` file looks like:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Entered pre-build phase"
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Entered build phase"
      - yarn global add react-scripts
      - cd client && yarn install
      - yarn run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Entered post-build phase"
```

Here are some other settings of my CodeBuild project:

1. Source: GitHub
2. Environment: Ubuntu 2.0 (latest)
3. BuildSpec: Using a file (listed above)
4. Artifacts: No Artifacts (I've also checked `Allow AWS CodeBuild to modify this service role so it can be used with this build project` as a Service Role Permission)
5. Logs: Using CloudLogs

[image]

Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an 'artifacts' section in your buildspec which is required to export build files to next stage (the files to be deployed to Elastic Beanstalk). Add the following in your buildspec at the end:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: ./client/build
```

(This assumes your build files are in the root of the build directory, adjust if not so.)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll definitely try that out.

My build files are generated at the `./client/build` path, and when I run my build command the files automatically generate there. 

Where does CodeBuild initially place them? Is it different from what happens when I run my build command on a local development environment?

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to read the artifact from correct directory. CodeBuild doesnt manipulate your files, the build command will generate the files and place them where they wish. CodeBuild can read your artifact from the dir you specify.

Comment: Tried adding the base-directory, but still no luck :( I'm guessing it has something to do the path specification. Does CodeBuild search for the path from the root of my application, or from the root of my build folder? I'm not sure if this helps, but when I ran `echo $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR` I got `/codebuild/output/src734170919/src `. Is this where CodeBuild is placing my build files?

Comment: To find current dir CodeBuild is currently in, just run 'pwd' in any phase.

Comment: Thank you for your advice so far! I also edited my question to include my CodeBuild configurations. I noticed that `Artifacts` upload location is blank. Before I used CodeBuild, and just used the `Source` and `Deploy` with Elastic Beanstalk this seemed to work fine. I'm not using an S3 bucket yet, and am wondering if it's a neccessity while using CodeBuild? (I'm not using a Dockerized image either)

Comment: Hey @AshishDommety, add a 'pwd && ls -l' run at the bottom of build stage. That will give you exacly the path were the artifact is being left, and that's where CodeBuild should be referenced to pick files from (in artifacts section).